# Guardar histograma en documento

Tags: python-3.x

tengo un dataframe de pandas. Sobre una de las variables (Edad) creo un histograma. Hasta aquí todo bien, pero me gustaría guardar esta imagen en un documento tipo word. ¿Hay forma de guardarla?
Estoy utilizando la librería docx

```
#El dataframe se llama datos

import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
#Creo el fichero .doc
document = Document()

#Puedo escribir en el
document.add_heading('Prueba', 0)

#Este es el histograma y lo que quiero es añadirlo a document
datos['Edad'].hist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es guardar el histograma en una imagen (que luego se elimina) utilizando el método `save_fig` de `matplotlib` y después cargarla usando el método `add_picture` de `docx`.

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
from docx import Document
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import os

# Inicialización de datos.
data = {"Nombre": ["Raul", "Pedro", "Jesus", "Marta", "Alberto", "Maria", "Jose", "Celia", "Laura", "Miguel"],
        "Edad": [15, 15, 13, 12, 14, 12, 14, 16, 15, 15]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Generamos el histograma y lo guardamos en un fichero png.
NOMBRE_HISTOGRAMA ="EdadHistograma.png"

fig = df["Edad"].hist()
pl.savefig(NOMBRE_HISTOGRAMA)

# Creamos el documento.
document = Document()

p = document.add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()

# Añadimos la imagen, cargando el fichero png.
r.add_picture(NOMBRE_HISTOGRAMA)

# Eliminamos el fichero png
os.remove("EdadHistograma.png")

# Guardamos el documento.
document.save('demo.docx')
```